in Angular Signals, can you use viewChild() + effect() to handle changes to a child element?
Let's say I want to know when a particular child element in my component is scrolled. Suppose I declare:
  contentPanel = viewChild.required<ElementRef>('contentPanel');
  contentScrollTop = computed(
    () => this.contentPanel().nativeElement.scrollTop,
  );

and then in the constructor an effect like:
effect(() => {
  console.log('scrolltop: ', this.contentScrollTop());
});

So this doesn't actually work but... is there a way this approach can work? or are properties of nativeElement outside of changes that Signals can detect? I can easily do this with an event listener, just curious if there's a more Signals-y way to do it.

As of 14/12/2024, there is no signal for HostListener or a signal for listening to event from HTML elements.
Until then we have to workaround to achieve this, I can think of two methods.

Using the HTML event with angular event binding (scroll):
We can listen for the scroll event on the element using (scroll) and call the scroll method.
<div style="height:300px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black"  (scroll)="scroll($event)" #contentPanel>
  <div style="height:1000px">
    Scrollable content!
  </div>
</div>

{{contentScrollTop()}}

On ngAfterViewInit we initial the initial value from the viewChild's scrollTop.
The scroll method will set the scrollTop each time the method is called.
contentPanel = viewChild.required<ElementRef>('contentPanel');
contentScrollTop = signal(0);

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.contentScrollTop.set(this.contentPanel().nativeElement?.scrollTop);
}

scroll(event: any) {
  this.contentScrollTop.set(event.target?.scrollTop);
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  DestroyRef,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  signal,
  viewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div style="height:300px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black"  (scroll)="scroll($event)" #contentPanel>
      <div style="height:1000px">
        Scrollable content!
      </div>
    </div>

    {{contentScrollTop()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  contentPanel = viewChild.required<ElementRef>('contentPanel');
  contentScrollTop = signal(0);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.contentScrollTop.set(this.contentPanel().nativeElement?.scrollTop);
  }

  scroll(event: any) {
    this.contentScrollTop.set(event.target?.scrollTop);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Using rxjs - fromEvent:
Listening to the changes using fromEvent scroll, we must ensure this is done on ngAfterViewInit since that is where the viewChild signal will have a value.
I am using takeUntilDestroyed and destroyRef to auto destroy the listener on component destroy.
Then we use tap to set the event value to the signal contentScrollTop, you can use this to achieve reactivity of signals.
destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
contentPanel = viewChild.required<ElementRef>('contentPanel');
contentScrollTop = signal(0);

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.contentPanel());
  fromEvent(this.contentPanel().nativeElement, 'scroll')
    .pipe(
      startWith(this.contentPanel().nativeElement?.scrollTop),
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
      tap((response: any) => {
        this.contentScrollTop.set(response.target?.scrollTop);
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}

Full Code:
import {
  Component,
  DestroyRef,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  signal,
  viewChild,
} from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { toSignal, takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';
import { fromEvent, tap, startWith } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div style="height:300px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid black"  #contentPanel >
      <div style="height:1000px">
        Scrollable content!
      </div>
    </div>

    {{contentScrollTop()}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
  contentPanel = viewChild.required<ElementRef>('contentPanel');
  contentScrollTop = signal(0);

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.contentPanel());
    fromEvent(this.contentPanel().nativeElement, 'scroll')
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.contentPanel().nativeElement?.scrollTop),
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
        tap((response: any) => {
          this.contentScrollTop.set(response.target?.scrollTop);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
